# Unknown job error on running service

Tags: linux, services, init-script, sysvinit

I am getting an 'start: Unknown job: elasticsearch' error when I try to do

```
    service elasticsearch start
```

When I run

```
    service --status-all
```

I can see elasticsearch present in the list. But I just cannot run start, stop and status commands.
Also when I run

```
    /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

the job runs with no issues.

Comment: Can you edit in the exact error you get? Do the errors always follow variations on the 'service elasticsearch' command?

Comment: Yes they do. For example for 'service elasticsearch status' command I get 'status: Unknown job: elasticsearch' error.

Comment: that's odd, because that's almost exactly what 'service --status-all' is calling. Are you using ubuntu, and hitting [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30796/upstart-script-doesnt-start) ?

Comment: I'm getting this error for some basic services like cron, cups, bluetooth;  but not for others like samba and ntp.  Ubuntu 14.  `service --status-all` shows all the usual suspects.